# On a special kind of six dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb C^9$ related to the primitive $9$-th root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\mu=e^{2\pi i/9}$ . Let $u_j:=(\mu^j,\mu^{2j}, \mu ^{3j},...,\mu^{9j})^T \in \mathbb C^9$, for $j=1,...,9$.

Let $V$ be the vector subspace of $\mathbb C^9$ spanned by $\{u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6,u_7\}$ .

I can show that there exists $A \in M_{3 \times 6} (\mathbb C)$ such that

$V=\{(x_1,...,x_9)\in \mathbb C^9 : (x_3,x_6,x_9)^T = A (x_1,x_2,x_4,x_5,x_7,x_8)^T \}$ .

If [On a special kind of $6$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb C^9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037761/on-a-special-kind-of-6-dimensional-vector-subspace-of-mathbb-c9)  is true, then this $A$ is unique and it is of the form $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 &a_2 &a_3&a_4&a_5&a_6 \\ a_5&a_6&a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4 \\ a_3&a_4&a_5&a_6&a_1&a_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Let $L$ be the smalles t subsfield of $\mathbb C$ generated by the entries of $A$.

I can show that $L \subseteq \mathbb Q(\mu) $ , and hence $L/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois-extension.

My question is : What is the extension degree $[L : \mathbb Q]$ ?

Since $[\mathbb Q(\mu):\mathbb Q]=\phi(9)=6$, so $[L:\mathbb Q]=1,2,3, $ or $6$, but exactly which one is it  ?

Comment: Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space spanned by $u_j, j \in [2,7]$. Show it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\mu]$. When looking at $x_n, gcd(n,9) = 1$, you are looking at $v \in V \mapsto ( \sigma_1(v), \ldots,\sigma_6(v)) \in W \subset \mathbb{Q}[\mu]^6, \sigma_l \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}[\mu]/\mathbb{Q})$ and again $W \cong \mathbb{Q}[\mu]$. Then $A$ is a linear map $\mathbb{Q}[\mu]^6 \to \mathbb{Q}[\mu^3]^3$ which can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @reuns: what is $W$ here again ... ? So what is the extension degree ?

Comment: Now that you know $L\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\mu)$ I think it would be better to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Q}(\mu)$. (And I have done this before my next comment!)

Comment: I don't think I agree with @reuns . If $A$ is rational then $V$ will be closed under the operation of applying the Galois Group of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu)$ to the components of the vectors. Then as $u_2\in V$ and $\sigma: \mu\mapsto\mu^2$ is an automorphism, we get that $\sigma^{5}(u_2)=u_1$ must be in $V$ as well. But $u_1, u_2,\dots, u_9$ are nine LI vectors, so we'd get that $V$ had dimension at least $7$ which it does not.

Comment: On the other hand $V$ is clearly closed under the automorphism $\mu\mapsto\mu^{-1}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let's re-write slightly using the facts you have established.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\mu]$ where $\mu$ is a primitive $9$-th root of unity. For $j=0,\dots, 8$ let $u_j$ be the column vector whose $i$-th component (for $i=0,\dots, 8$) is $\mu^{ji}$.

Let $M$ be the matrix whose columns are $u_0,\dots, u_8$. Note that we have the orthogonality conditions $\bar{M}^{T}M=9I$. Amongst other things this shows that the nine columns are linearly independent.

It is convenient to re-order the rows and columns in this order: $0,3,6,1,2,4,8,7,5$.

Let $V$ be the $K$-span of $u_2,u_3,u_4,u_4,u_6,u_7$.

We are given that $V$ is the null space of some $B:=[I_3\ A]$, and that the $A$ in question is unique. Again, for convenience we've replaced $A$ of the question by its negative. Let us then find $A$ explicitly.

As the columns $u_2,u_3,u_4,u_4,u_6,u_7$ are in the null space of $B$ the rows of $B$ are orthogonal to these six vectors. However, by the orthogonality relations we have that the three rows $\bar{u_{0}}^T,\bar{u_{1}}^T,\bar{u_{8}}^T$ are orthogonal to the six vectors. These three rows form the matrix
$$
B_1:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega  &\mu^{-1} & \mu^{-2} & \mu^{-4}&\mu & \mu^2 & \mu^4\\
1 & \omega & \omega^2 &\mu & \mu^2 & \mu^4 &\mu^{-1} & \mu^{-2} & \mu^{-4}\\
\end{bmatrix}=[\Omega\ \Delta\ \bar{\Delta}], \text{  say,}
$$ 
where $\omega:=\mu^3$.

Now $\bar{\Omega}^{T}B_1$ also annihilates the six vectors $u_2,u_3,u_4,u_4,u_6,u_7$, and as $\Omega$ also satisfies the orthogonality conditions we have
$$
\bar{\Omega}^{T}B_1=[ 3I\ \ (\bar{\Omega}^{T}\Delta)\ \ (\bar{\Omega}^{T}\bar{\Delta})]. 
$$

By the uniqueness of $A$, then, we have
$$
A=\frac{1}{3}[(\bar{\Omega}^{T}\Delta)\ \ (\bar{\Omega}^{T}\bar{\Delta})].
$$

It is now routine to calculate the entries of $A$. They all lie in the degree $3$ extension $\mathbb{Q} [\mu+\mu^{-1}, \mu^2+\mu^{-2},\mu^4+\mu^{-4}]$ and they are not all rational.